# Selecting up_votes - down_votes as total_votes and ordering them with laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

Hi there i have some trouble getting the sum of the following query and orderby the highest sum.

```
Counters::orderBy('up_votes - down_votes as total_votes', 'DESC')->take(10)->get()
```

Comment: Your query is wrong, so be specific, ei. I want X, I get Y (or error Z) in order to get help. In this case you need raw select and simple order by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counters::select(DB::raw('*, up_votes - down_votes as total_votes'))